Get the distinct names an account has prior the last day in TERADATA or Oracle without using stored procedures, just queries
I need to calculate the distinct names an account had, where I have the date of each update the account had:



Date
ACCOUNT
NAME




2024-01-01
A
XOXO


2024-01-02
A
XOXO


2024-01-02
A
OXXO


2024-01-04
A
XOOX


2024-01-05
A
OOXO


2024-01-06
A
XOXO



So for the date 2024-01-01 prior to that date, I don't have any record with account A with another NAME but for the records on day 2024-01-02 for both records I already have a unique record being XOXO, so on the third day, I only have 2 distinct NAMES prior that date.
So the result of my query has to be something like this:



DATE
ACCOUNT
COUNT DISTINCT NAME




2024-01-01
A
NULL


2024-01-02
A
1


2024-01-04
A
2


2024-01-05
A
3


2024-01-06
A
4



I've already tried PARTITION BY ACCOUNT ORDER BY NAME.
And this condition counts every name as a unique name, even if it's repeated like XOXO
DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by ACCOUNT Order by NAME ASC) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by ACCOUNT Order by NAME DESC) - 1 as COUNTP

This condition always returned the total distinct Names per record, even for the date 2024-02-02 where I was expecting just one record counted.
Regards!

Why does the count increase to 4 on 2024-01-06, given that name XOXO has already occurred earlier?

But it doesn't need to count the record of that day, given that I just want the distinct names prior that date, not calculating the name of 2024-01-06. So it's just counting the XOXO of prior dates and OXXO, XOOX and OOXO.

You can do it without a correlated sub-query by using the ROW_NUMBER analytic function to number the occurrences of each name/account pairing and then, using an inline-view, to total the first appearances of each pairing:
SELECT DISTINCT
       dt,
       account,
       SUM(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (
         PARTITION BY account
         ORDER BY dt
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING
       ) AS count_distinct_name
FROM   (
  SELECT dt,
         account,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account, name ORDER BY dt) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
)
ORDER BY account, dt;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Dt, ACCOUNT, NAME) AS
SELECT DATE '2024-01-01', 'A', 'XOXO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-02', 'A', 'XOXO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-02', 'A', 'OXXO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-04', 'A', 'XOOX' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-05', 'A', 'OOXO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2024-01-06', 'A', 'XOXO' FROM DUAL;;

Outputs:



DT
ACCOUNT
COUNT_DISTINCT_NAME




2024-01-01 00:00:00
A
null


2024-01-02 00:00:00
A
1


2024-01-04 00:00:00
A
2


2024-01-05 00:00:00
A
3


2024-01-06 00:00:00
A
4



fiddle

Thanks! This is the best approach and indeed has given me the answer!

The answer from MT0 may work for Oracle. Teradata does not have RANGE BETWEEN but a similar approach with ROWS BETWEEN will work:
SELECT 
       "date",
       "ACCOUNT",
       SUM(SUM(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN 1 END)) OVER (
         PARTITION BY "ACCOUNT"
         ORDER BY "date"
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
       ) AS count_distinct_NAME
FROM   (
  SELECT "date",
         "ACCOUNT",
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "ACCOUNT", NAME ORDER BY "date") AS rn
  FROM   table_NAME
) occurrence_number
GROUP BY "ACCOUNT", "date"
ORDER BY "ACCOUNT", "date";


With the GROUP BY clause being applied before the analytic function, so there is only one row per day, then, yes, ROWS BETWEEN works just like RANGE BETWEEN (when the filtering with DISTINCT happens after the analytic function is applied).

You could use a correlated subquery here:
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.Date,
    t1.ACCOUNT,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.NAME) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.ACCOUNT = t1.ACCOUNT AND t2.Date < t1.Date) D_COUNT
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    t1.ACCOUNT,
    t1.Date;


It produced 0 for the first date, which it's great, but for the other date it just got 1 as a result.

Remove t1.NAME from the SELECT and ORDER BY clauses, and add GROUP BY t1.ACCOUNT, t1.DATE just before ORDER BY. This is closer to your results (where multiple entries with the same date and acc are aggregated.

Now I get just 0 or 1, but not the results as expected. Thanks!
